# how do I retrieve 34 from "#34 PREEMPT Mon Mar 25 14:24:26 SGT 2013"

Tags: linux

I am new on Linux, how do I retrieve "34" from `uname -v` command?

My `uname -v` command result is `#34 PREEMPT Mon Mar 25 14:24:26 SGT 2013`

I wanna the number 34 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to show only the matching part of a line (`-o`) matching a `#` followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`):

```
uname -v | grep -o '#[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: thanks. `uname -v | grep -o '[0-9]\+'`  I need the number only.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo '#34 PREEMPT ...' | sed 's/^#\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
34
```

You can also make that easier with `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/^#([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

Comment: thanks: `uname -v | sed 's/^#\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'`  this work for me. i like sed, but zero knowledge on it.

Comment: great, got back to my program, one time use it only. I will mark @Johnsyweb as answer as you know both of the answers are correct. I up vote your answer as well.